# Verify that an eigenvector is orthogonal to 2 other eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-mathematics

Verify that the eigenvector v3=(4,-2,1) corresponding to the eigenvalue e2=16 is orthogonal to the eigenvectors v1=(1/2,1,0) and v2=(-1/4,0,1) (both) corresponding to eigenvalue e1=-5

All I can think to do is to just do the dot product of v1 . v3  and  v2 . v3   and if the dot product =0 then v3 is orthogonal to them?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you should do; that's the definition of orthogonality.

Comment: Did you take the dot product? What did you get?

Comment: @RyanHowe I got 0 for both so it worked, im just worried that it isnt sufficient because its an assignment question.

Comment: @KaylaMartin nope, you did what you were supposed to do.

Comment: Okay great, thank you :)

Comment: If the vectors are orthogonal, does that say anything about their linear independence?